# x86 Assembly language Jump on overflow

Tags: assembly, x86, overflow

I'm having some difficulty understanding the overflow flag. I'm using the jump on overflow instruction (`JO`) but it doesn't seem to jump when the overflow has occurred. I can't seem to find anything on how to use it in the book I'm reading. Here is part of the code:

```
call getdec$
mov  bx,9
mul  bx
JO   loc1
call putdec$
```

It put outs the incorrect value so I know it overflows and it doesn't jump to `loc1`. Am I just using the `JO` incorrectly?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the value in `ax` before you call `mul`?

Comment: I used 55555 so that it goes above the 65,535 limit for unsigned.

Comment: Are you sure that `ax` indeed contains this value? What happens if you insert `mov ax, 55555` before `mul`?

Comment: Overflow flag is for signed overflow. You want carry flag here.

Comment: @FrankKotler: Intel's documentation for `MUL` states that _"The OF and CF flags are set to 0 if the upper half of the result is 0; otherwise, they are set to 1."_

Comment: @Michael You're right. That's what I get for posting before looking it up or trying it. Thanks for the correction! So... why isn't MKR's program jumping?

Comment: That's very hard to say without seeing more code, like the `getdec$` function.